# Android Studio 3.5: Generate Signed Bundle does not get any results

Tags: cordova, android-studio-3.5

I followed these steps:

9. In top menu bar, click on Build > Clean Project.
10. In top menu bar, click on Project > Build Bundle(s)/APK(s) > Build Bundle(s).
11. The Event Log pane will give the time and status of your build:

    08:19   Build Bundle(s)

    App bundle(s) generated successfully for 1 module:

    Module 'app': locate or analyze the app bundle.

You can click on "locate" to show the .aab file in the Finder window, in platforms/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/debug/app-debug.aab

After this I followed:

1. In top menu bar, Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK...
2. You'll get the options to sign an Android App Bundle (top option) or an APK. The Android App Bundle is selected by default. Click on Next.
3. The Generate Signed Bundle or APK window has several fields to fill out. "app" should be in the Module field.

I filled out the fields.

When all is said and done, Event Log did not display anything regarding the signed bundle. There is no change in the .aab file (I checked the date/time). I kept the export encrypted kit location as Desktop, but there is no .pepk file there.

Event Log does not display any errors or warnings.

(I wrote a complete article on my process here: https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2019/09/17/making-an-android-app-bundle-aab-file-from-a-cordova-project/)

Comment: This happened to me when I had a typo in my alias.

Answer (score 40):

I faced the same issue. I solved it by trying to sign it as apk instead of bundle and in that case android studio gave me log details. In my case, the problem was the key password that was wrong. After i confirmed that I was able to successfully build a signed apk, I tried to build a bundle and it worked.

Comment: In my case, the jks file path was somehow overridden, so the studio could not verify the JKS.
Android studio must also give us the error for the aab file as they suggest for the aab file in the play console.

Answer (score 16):

In my situation the password was wrong. I added extra space.

Comment: omg, i can't believe this was an issue, let me teach the Android Studio Developers about String.trim(). I had same problem

Answer (score 8):

I had to replace the "Key Store Password" and "Key Password" with `storePassword` and `keyPassword` values from  `key.properties` file.
The frustrating part is that Android Studio doesn't throw any error about these wrong values and you have to figure out by guessing.
Once you provide correct values everything works like a charm.

Comment: In my situation, I had made up an alias rather than selecting it from the little folder icon.  Once I did that, it worked.  And of course, no errors were generated...

Answer (score 6):

Verify the key store password and key password.

Add them again with the same information.

In my case after a generation both changed automatically without any action.

[image]

Comment: yeah, I just retyped both my passwords, and changed my `key alias` to what it had been once before, and it worked after.

Answer (score 2):

i actually faced the same problem, it came after I changed the project folder and renamed it. that meant it was not facing the final destination.

it would actually build an apk, but building a signed bundle(AAB) for play store never returned any results.
do the following to resolve that problem.
1.In top menu bar, click on Build > Clean Project.
2. In top menu bar, click on Build > Rebuild Project, so it rebuilt it with the required settings.
Good luck

Answer (score -1):

In my case the key or the file to sign apk had to be in the same folder of the project